# How to add an short description field in manage category in admin with magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I want to add a short description field in manage category in admin and want to show the description value in front end.I tried but unable to do that.
I am adding a custom attribute `app/etc/modules/Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute>
    </modules>
</config>
```

then added in  `app/code/community/Atwix/CustomCategoryAttribute/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <resources>
            <add_category_attribute>
                <setup>
                    <module>Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute>
            <add_category_attribute_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute_write>
            <add_category_attribute_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

then added in `app/code/community/Atwix/CustomCategoryAttribute/sql/add_category_attribute/mysql4-install-0.0.1.php`

```
<?php
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'custom_attribute', array(
    'group'         => 'General',
    'input'         => 'textarea',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'Custom attribute',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));

$this->endSetup();
```

this will create an extra field in manage category general section.now i want to show the value in

```
app/design/frontend/default/alpha/template/catalog/product/productlisting.phtml   page
```

so i put this code

```
<?php if($_customAttribute = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getCustomAttribute()): ?>
    <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_customAttribute, 'custom_attribute') ?>
<?php endif; ?>
but it shows error
```

Fatal error: Call to a member function getCustomAttribute() on a non-object

I don't know how to show the custom attribut value in front end.
If anyone knows this,then please help me out.
Thanks!

Comment: Why not use the default description field of category?

Comment: Do you get Current Category in productlisting.phtml page?

Comment: I wrote this to know whether current category is coming or not <?php echo $this->getCurrentCategory(); exit; ?>  but it is not coming

Comment: no i need two description field in manage category

Answer (score 1):

No need of all the above stuff dude. Just Place these two files.

Create a **mysql4-install-1.0.0.php** at the following path.
Place the below code at their following paths:

`/app/code/local/Test/Customcatattrb/sql/customcatattrb_setup`

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$attribute  = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label'=> 'Deal name',
    'input' => 'textarea',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'default' => "",
    'group' => "General Information"
);
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'deal_name', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
```

Create a config.xml at the following path
**/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/local/Test/Customcatattrb/etc**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Test_Customcatattrb>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Test_Customcatattrb>
  </modules>
    <global>
      <resources>
          <customcatattrb_setup>
            <setup>
              <module>Test_Customcatattrb</module>
              <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
              <use>default_setup</use>
            </connection>
          </customcatattrb_setup>
      </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

And I think you are aware of the **Test_Customcatattrb.xml** at **app/etc/modules**. Now just go to the admin and check. There will be a new field named withe 'Deal Name' in the general information block.